# Bootstrap + sortable com JQuery, problema com helper

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, bootstrap

Estou utilizando um template do bootstrap para fazer um pequeno supervisório. Nele, adicionei duas áreas de sortable connected lists, disponíveis no JQuery. As `ul's` com os elementos das listas estão com atributo `overflow-y: scroll`, para quando a quantidade de itens for elevada. Até aí funciona bem, porém, ao tentar arrastar o elemento de uma lista para outra, ele arrasta o scroll da própria `ul` sem parar e, fora da própria lista o elemento simplesmente desaparece e só reaparece quando é solto na outra lista.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que estou executando é:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="box-body config">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <ul id="sortable" class="list-inline connectedSortable">
                  <li class="btn-default" style="list-style: none">Teste 2</li>
                  <li class="btn-default" style="list-style: none">Teste</li>
                  <li class="btn-default" style="list-style: none">Teste 2</li>
                  <li class="btn-default" style="list-style: none">Teste</li>
                  <li class="btn-default" style="list-style: none">Teste 2</li>
                  <li class="btn-default" style="list-style: none">Teste 2</li>
                  <li class="btn-default" style="list-style: none">Teste</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$( "#sortable, #sortable2" ).sortable({connectWith: ".connectedSortable", 
placeholder: "dashed-placeholder"});
```

**CSS**:

```
#sortable, #sortable2  {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;

    }
#sortable li, #sortable2 li {
    margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
     }
```

Tentei também adicionando um `helper: 'clone'` no JS porém sem sucesso.
Existe alguma outra maneira de fazer o item aparecer fora do `ul` inicial?
Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido! Adicionei os seguintes atributos ao `.sortable`:

```
$("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
  appendTo: document.body,
  helper: "clone",
```

Fonte: [StackOverflow - jQuery UI Sortable connected list css issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684849/jquery-ui-sortable-connected-list-css-issues)